# Construction of non null section on a linear vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

I think this is quite basic.

Say $E \xrightarrow{\pi} M$ is a linear vector bundle on a smooth variety  with positive transition functions, prove that it is a trivial bundle.

In few words I have to find a non null section $\sigma: M \rightarrow E$

Answer (score 0):

I belive that the dimension of the fibres of $E$ is $1$. Let $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ be the trivialization for which the transition functions are positive. Take a partition of unity $f_i$ associated to $(U_i)$, on $U_i$ you have a non trivial section $s_i$ which is strictly positive. Write $s=\sum f_is_i$, it is a non vanishing section.

Comment: Let $g_{ij}: U_i \cap U_j \in GL_n (\Bbb R)$ be the transition function between $U_i$ and $U_j$, and $\chi_{i} : \pi^{-1}(U_i) \rightarrow U_i \times \Bbb R$.
Can I set $s_i = \chi_i^{-1} (p, g_{ij}(p) v)$ for some $v \neq 0 \; \in \Bbb R$ and $p \in U_i \cap U_j$? That's the way?